# Bandwidth Concerns for 2 Webcams and an Arduino in a USB Hub

Tags: usb, bandwidth, webcam, arduino, opencv

I'm working on a robotics project using an Arduino and two Logitech C920 Pro webcams.

I'm trying to keep everything nice and tidy so I thought I could connect the Arduino and the two C920s to a powered USB 2.0 hub ([this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0002AFZVM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) one to be specific). Both webcams will run at 640x480 @ 30FPS (some more tech specs about the webcam is available [here](https://www.superbiiz.com/detail.php?name=LT-C920)).

My concern is bandwidth related. I have an OpenCV program running which will take 3-5 frames from each camera one at a time (not at the same time) and perform some colour detection. Then, commands will be issued to the Arduino to move 7 stepper motors depending on the outcome of the colour detection. I might have to perform the colour detection process multiple times depending on how well the results turned out. In that case, a command will be issued to the Arduino which will move the stepper motors so the webcams can get a better view of the subject and repeat. I am concerned about this because I need commands to be issued to the Arduino in a timely manner.

Would I be at risk of saturating the USB 2.0 bandwidth with a system like this? If both webcams are connected and powered, but are only being read from one at a time, would the bandwidth be lower than streaming two of them at the same time?

Thanks!